# T setter with index and object in java

Tags: java, setter

This code is wrong. It must be correct according to me but I'm confusing. I have been working on this for hours. There must be something I missed. I'm very very beginner coder. I cannot think alghoritmic like you. Could you look at this?

```
public T set(int index, T t) {

        MyArrayListElement<T> element = getElement(index); 
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
              throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
            T old = getElement(index);
            getElement(index) = t;
            return old;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Instead of `getElement(index) = t;` you probably want something like `setElement(index, t);`.  And then you'd need to write the `setElement` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:

https://github.com/tdgunes/ozucourses/tree/master/CS102/Homework%201

You must replace

```
getElement(index) = t;
```

by

```
set(index, t)
```

to set an element in your list.

Answer (score 3):

One issue I see here is the following.

You cannot assign this way: `getElement(index) = t;`.

The left side must be a variable.

What you need here is a call something like this.

`setElement(index, t);`